# Storing Data on an online Server

Tags: java, android

I have made an app and now I want to my app to save the name of the users when they enter it on an online server where it can be stored and can be viewed by me.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this by creating a backend server in any of the back end technologies like java,php,.net and communicate from ur app to server using webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is kind of messy, but I will try to explain it to you as simple as possible.

1) You will need an web server with data base and service API to which you will post the users. Try reading more about this or add other tags as it's not so much in android hands.

2) In the app you will need to connect to the API service and POST the data to the server where you will receive it. For this case try reading more about [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) as it will reduce your pains, big time.

And in the near future try asking more concrete questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). It's free of charge for basic projects and has a good documentation. Also it's main platform target is Android.

Answer (score 0):

Install a database to the server to store the names.
Install something like tomcat to run a web service on it.
Create the web service to accept data entries and store them in the database.
Call your web service from your app with the given username as parameter.